# How to add a UI to a WiX 3 installer?

Tags: user-interface, wix, wix3.6, wix-extension

I've tried `<UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" />`, but I get "Unresolved reference to symbol WixUI:WixUIMinimal". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The wixui extension is no longer wixui.wixlib. It was rolled into the WixUIExtension.

If you are on the command line, add `-ext WixUIExtension` to the call to light.exe.

If you have a WiX project in Visual Studio, add a reference to "WixUIExtension" by right clicking on "References" in the [Solution Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Other_tools).

See the [WiXUI Dialog Sets page for WIX3](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/).

Comment: If anybody's wondering where the dll is, it should be in `C:\Program Files (x64)\WiX Toolset [version]\bin\ `.

Comment: Why they've decided not to include any Visual Studio instruction on that documentation page is beyond me.

Comment: For your 2017 question, you are probably using NuGet to fetch the WixInstaller.  If so, the location of the DLL is your solution folder\packages\Wix<ver>\tools\WixUIExtension.dll.  I'm adding all this to my MSI project (not the EXE bundle).  It compiles.  LOL

Comment: FWIW you need to add the DLL reference to the Wix project in your solution.

Answer (score 9):

If you use the `.wixproj` directly via MSBuild, without Visual Studio, the required modification is to add this:

```
<Project ...>
  ...
  <ItemGroup>
    <WixExtension Include="WixUIExtension">
      <HintPath>$(WixToolPath)WixUIExtension.dll</HintPath>
      <Name>WixUIExtension</Name>
    </WixExtension>
  </ItemGroup>
  ...
</Project>
```

Comment: You can insert this code snippet also with **Visual Studio**. ... **unload the project** in the project explorer with right-click to the project name. Then make **double click** to the project name. The `*.wixproj` file opens and you **can edit** it. After saving reload the project and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

See [Re: (WiX-users) How to get off the ground with WixUI_Minimal?](http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg03614.html)

Answer (score 1):

Below is a link to a good example on how to custimize the WixUIExtensions.

[Customised UIs for Wix](http://neilsleightholm.blogspot.com/2008/08/customised-uis-for-wix.html#links)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add reference of WixUIExtension in your WIX project to resolve this issue.