# Reference WixUI Error

Tags: wix, wix3.7

Enviorment:Win7+VS2012+Wix3.7.

Complile error:

> Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixUI:WixUI_InstallDir' in section
>   'Product:{9E327731-0EAC-4A02-9C3C-9C136ACCE05B}'

Code is the follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="{9E327731-0EAC-4A02-9C3C-9C136ACCE05B}" Name="SetupProject2" Language="1033" Version="1.1.1.1" Manufacturer="Anser" UpgradeCode="61eb40a6-21d9-4f23-9c9e-078b98707371">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SetupProject2" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR">INSTALLDIR</Property>
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir"/>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="SetupProject2" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
      <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent"> -->
      <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
      <!-- </Component> -->
      <Component Id="ProductComponent" DiskId="1" Guid="{65F464D6-BC0B-4679-9546-CF8B6CFCE184}">     
        <File Name='test.exe' Source="test.exe" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I can't find the reason.Who can help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a UI to a WiX 3 installer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596919/how-to-add-a-ui-to-a-wix-3-installer)

Comment: it's sort of a duplicate, but actually the specific error message written in this specific question is what brought me here, which eventually led me to the duplicate that has the answer, so I think this question should stay and I'll upvote

Answer (score 31):

Reference `WixUIExtension.dll` in the project.

I refer to the similar question in the follow site.
[How to add a UI to a WiX 3 installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596919/how-to-add-a-ui-to-a-wix-3-installer)

Comment: Assuming you have the toolset installed, It is located on: %PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\